# OCR Deep Learning Software

Tags: database, ocr, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning

I have a question about a possible software solution for a problem. I work in a very busy psychiatric private practice that handles large amounts of paperwork. We would like to create a more efficient way of getting paper copies into digital format. We use scanners but the current process is just not quick enough. My ultimate goal would be to have a software that could OCR a stack of random papers, use Deep Learning to recognize and sort each page into a specified folder. The Deep Learning would reference a database of every patient in the practice roster.The sort process would be based on patient's name, date of birth, and any other tag simultaneously.

Are there any available software solutions for Windows 8 or Windows 10 OS on the market today? Pricing is not a factor right now I just want to know if it is possible to solve this problem with any software or if a software could be made from the ground up.

Comment: OCR is always _potentially_ error prone so using it for patient records would open you up to the risk of a lot of lawsuits. The real answer it to make it simpler to capture the data directly into digital form and stop generating all of that paper.